# docker-compose using entrypoint from wrong folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I've been banging my head against this issue for quite a long time now.

I will try to explain as clearly as I can the situation I am in.

I have two different projects.

The first project has this `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  spaceflights-backend-database:
    hostname: spaceflights-database-host
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: jBmfXzQKEck8TQco
      POSTGRES_USER: spaceflights
      POSTGRES_DB: spaceflights
  spaceflights-backend-application:
    build:
        context: ./application
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    hostname: spaceflights-application-host
    image: spaceflights/backend-application
    working_dir: /home/node/spaceflights-application
    volumes:
      - "../filesystem:/home/node/spaceflights-application"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - spaceflights-backend-database
```

Here is the Dockerfile content:

```
FROM node:latest

ENV COMPOSE_RPOJECT_NAME=spaceflights-frontend

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    nano \
    screen \
    htop \
    bash \
    dumb-init \
    postgresql

# Entrypoint
COPY . /docker-files/
RUN chmod +x /docker-files/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--", "/docker-files/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["bash", "-c", "node src/app.mjs"]
```

Here is the `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

echo 'Installing packages'

yarn install

echo 'Setting up database data'

node initialization/setup.mjs

exec "$@"
```

The folder structure is:

[image]

This project works like a charm, no complaint, everything is top notch.

I have this second project:

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  spaceflights-frontend-main:
    container_name: spaceflights-frontend-main
    image: spaceflights/frontend-main
    build:
        context: ./application
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      REACT_APP_HOST: vagrant-docker
      REACT_APP_PORT: 8080
      REACT_APP_API_HOST: vagrant-docker
      REACT_APP_API_PORT: 3000
    hostname: spaceflights-frontend-application
    working_dir: /home/node/spaceflights-application
    volumes:
      - "../filesystem:/home/node/spaceflights-application"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    nano \
    bash 

RUN yarn install
RUN yarn global add serve

CMD ["bash", "-c", "serve -l ${REACT_APP_PORT} -s build > /dev/null"]
```

No `docker-entrypoint.sh` here.

The folder structure is:

[image]

**After stopping and removing every single container, which means `docker container ls` returns an empty list** and trying to run this guy, for some reason beyond my understanding, it executes the `docker-entrypoint.sh` from the first project.

I tried multiple things:

- Using a `.env`: It does not change anything.
- Using `docker-compose -p ...` to define a project name, it does not help.
- Removing all the `container_name` in the `docker-compose.yml`. Still does not work.
- Renaming the `docker` folder to two different things in each project. Nothing good.
- Various combinations of all of the above.

I start both project using the same command: `docker-compose up -d --build`.

I am really clueless here, I just don't understand why it is so confused. The projects aren't even in the same folder (obviously considering the directory structure) and I run `docker-compose up -d --build` in the `docker` folder.

Any help would be really appreciated!

<3

Comment: At some point, did the `docker-compose.yml` specify both `build:` and also `image: node`?  If you `docker pull node:latest` to get the current version from Docker Hub, does it improve things?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DavidMaze, I actually found the solution this weekend. Turns out that when you specify `image:` it means you want to build an image with this name, not use this image. I had to pull my node image again and then rework my Dockerfile.
I'm going to post a full explanation of my solution so it may help other people.
Nonetheless your answer would have given me the solution I think.